# How to encrypt with a public Key and encoded using Base64 using Javascript (NodeJS, etc)

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, encryption

```
var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
var key = new NodeRSA();
var public= '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----'+publicKey+'-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
const text = "hello";
key.importKey(public,"pkcs1");
var encrypted = key.encrypt(text, 'base64');
console.log(encrypted);
```

I'm trying to encrypt the text using node-rsa, and the documentation of what I'm trying to encrypt says it must be encrypted using encription in RSA with PKCS1-v1_5 scheme.
I tried using this piece of code and it works but when I send the encrypted message to the API (I cant disclose which), it doesnt accept it and shows this error message:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"rsaCryptService.decrypt.wrongKey","title":"Wrong public key.","detail":"The public key you are using is invalid. Please use the one we provided you."}]}
```

I made an alternate version in Python and that works but I need it to work using Javascript

Is using Django or Flask an option?

HELP !!! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let forge = require("node-forge");
var pki = forge.pki;
var pem = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n'+key+'-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
// convert a PEM-formatted public key to a Forge public key
var publicKey = pki.publicKeyFromPem(pem);
var text = "message";
const encrypted = publicKey.encrypt(text);
console.log("encrypted:", forge.util.encode64(encrypted));
```

Already found the solution to my problem.
Hoping to help someone else! :D